# Notice: Undefined index: dtime

Tags: php, undefined-index

I am new to php. I wrote an sql query in my php file to return the most popular hour from a table.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT HOUR(dtime) as Hr,COUNT(*) AS Cnt
                       FROM lewis_locations
                       GROUP BY Hour(dtime)
                       ORDER BY Cnt DESC
                       LIMIT 1");  
 if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // looping through all results
        // products node
    $response["lewis_locations"] = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $stop = array();
        $stop["id"] = @$row["id"];
        $stop["name"] = @$row["name"];
        $stop["dtime"] = $row["dtime"];

        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["lewis_locations"], $stop);
 }
```

But when I try to get the result I get the error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: dtime
```

The error is located in this line:

```
$stop["dtime"] = $row["dtime"];
```

I understand if i suppress the error with the @ operator like so:

```
$stop["dtime"] = @$row["dtime"];
```

the error will go away. But it does not fix my problem as I am left with a Null vaule result. I have used this php code with other sql queries and I have been successful in getting the right value. So why wouldn't the @ operator work this time? I have researched what the @ operator does but I do not understand its inconsistency.. And is there a quick fix for this?

Comment: You only selected "Hr" and "Cnt" in your query, so only $row["Hr"] and $row["Cnt"] exist. You have each column you wish in your select statement.

Answer (score 0):

The only columns or values you are selecting in your query: `SELECT HOUR(dtime) as Hr,COUNT(*) AS Cnt` are "Hr" and "Cnt". If you want id, name and dtime, you need to select them.

Comment: Spot on. Silly mistake. Thanks for the feedback.